# How to detect email from secure services like Proton or Hush

Tags: javascript, html, email, security

I have a website that is legal and legit. I'm getting users from Proton, Hush and the like trying to register. I caught a few bad actors lately. Before I go down the path of PhoneText validation, I'd like to try and spend $5 on this $5 problem.

I'm currently validating their email address like this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
function validate() {
   var emailID = document.orderForm.con_email.value;
   bademailPos = emailID.indexOf("proton");

   if (bademailpos > 1) {
      alert("Sorry. We can't deal with these types of email addresses. Got a normal one?")
      document.orderForm.con_email.focus() ;
      return false;
   }

   return( true );
}
//-->
</script>
```

Is there a list of these types of mail system mail formats? For example, "protonmail.com", "Hushmail.com", etc. so I can identify them?

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from RFC5322 email definition, you can use following regex to filter specific email provider accounts:

```
\b[\w.!#$%&’*+\/=?^`{|}~-]+@(protonmail|hush)+(?:\.[\w-]+)*\b
```

So, your code should include following lines:

```
function checkBannedEmailProvider(email) {
  var re = new RegExp('\b[\w.!#$%&’*+\/=?^`{|}~-]+@(protonmail|hush)+(?:\.[\w-]+)*\b');
  var OK = re.exec(email);
  if (!OK) {
     console.error(email + ' : Email provider not permitted. '); 
  } else {
     alert(OK[0] + ' : Valid email provider. ');}
  } 

var email = 'asd@protonmail.com'
checkBannedEmailProvider(email);
```

Already verified regex string [here](https://regex101.com/r/cO8lqs/18659) and js code [here](https://js.do/code/427022)